# Hanging pictures on a sloping plasterboard wall...?

Tags: drywall, walls, hanging

So I've just moved house and I have some fairly heavy pictures (one painting, one framed picture) that I want to hang on my wall. Problem is, the walls are sloped (I'm in an attic room) and they're plasterboard.

I was wondering how I can hang them securely to the plasterboard and match the angle of the slope?

Thanks

Comment: Technically, I think you're talking about fastening pictures to the sloping *ceiling* above a partial height vertical *knee-wall*.

Answer (score 1):

If the frames aren't important & are at least a few mm's wide, then it would be best to actually secure the pictures by drilling the frame & screwing them directly to the wall. Either, directly into the structural framing or into one of many available wall anchors, I prefer one's that flare-out behind the plasterboard.

You can also accomplish the same result by using large washers on screws applied to the outside of the frames (2 on bottom & 1 on each side), so there's no drilling. But, the washers can be a bit ugly. So, the better option would be a Mirror Hanger type of Wrap From Behind clip (left) or Perimeter Offset Clamp (middle) or you may have to bend & possibly cut your own out of L-Brackets or Corner Braces (right) to accommodate thicker frames (Wrap From Behind application).

[image: Picture Hangers]

These will handle a very good deal of weight & frequent bumping into & can be padded with tape or felt to protect the frames.